# Switching left and right adjoints in recollement situations

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, higher-category-theory, triangulated-categories, perverse-sheaves

In Fascieaux pervers, Beilinson, Bernstein and Deligne define a recollement situation as a triple of triangulated categories $\mathcal{D}_U,\mathcal{D}_F$ and $\mathcal{D}$, together with functors
$$
i_*\colon \mathcal{D}_F\to \mathcal{D},\qquad j_*\colon \mathcal{D}\to \mathcal{D}_U
$$
with suitable properties. In particular, $i_*$ has both a left adjoint $i^*$ and a right adjoint $i^!$. Beilinson, Bernstein and Deligne show that, in this situation, given
$t$-structures $(\mathcal{D}^{\leq0}_U,\mathcal{D}^{\geq 0}_U)$ on $\mathcal{D}_U$ and $(\mathcal{D}^{\leq0}_F,\mathcal{D}^{\geq 0}_F)$ on $\mathcal{D}_F$ one obtains a $t$-structure $(\mathcal{D}^{\leq0},\mathcal{D}^{\geq 0})$ on $\mathcal{D}$ by setting
$$
\mathcal{D}^{\leq0}=\{K\in \mathcal{D}\,|\, j^*K\in\mathcal{D}_U^{\leq 0} \text{ and } i^*K\in \mathcal{D}^{\leq0}_F\}
$$
$$
\mathcal{D}^{\geq0}=\{K\in \mathcal{D}\,|\, j^*K\in\mathcal{D}_U^{\geq 0} \text{ and } i^!K\in \mathcal{D}^{\geq0}_F\}
$$
It is not hard to check that this is indeed a $t$-structure on $\mathcal{D}$. One may wonder what happens by switching the role of the left and right adjoint of $i_*$ in the above definition, i.e., if one tries to define a $t$-structure by setting
$$
\tilde{\mathcal{D}}^{\leq0}=\{K\in \mathcal{D}\,|\, j^*K\in\mathcal{D}_U^{\leq 0} \text{ and } i^!K\in \mathcal{D}^{\leq0}_F\}
$$
$$
\tilde{\mathcal{D}}^{\geq0}=\{K\in \mathcal{D}\,|\, j^*K\in\mathcal{D}_U^{\geq 0} \text{ and } i^*K\in \mathcal{D}^{\geq0}_F\}
$$
The argument that shows that $(\mathcal{D}^{\leq0},\mathcal{D}^{\geq 0})$ is a $t$-structure breaks down if one tries to adapt it to $(\tilde{\mathcal{D}}^{\leq0},\tilde{\mathcal{D}}^{\geq 0})$, precisely since the adjoints are not in the right place. However this is not a proof that $(\tilde{\mathcal{D}}^{\leq0},\tilde{\mathcal{D}}^{\geq 0})$ is not a $t$-structure, but only that it is not obviously so. And indeed, if one tries to set up a recollement situation in the much more symmetric setting of stable $\infty$-categories (where all constructions show a very nice symmetric behaviour due to the fact that every pullback is a pushout and vice versa), then it seems that not only also $(\tilde{\mathcal{D}}^{\leq0},\tilde{\mathcal{D}}^{\geq 0})$ is a $t$-structure, but that this actually coincides with $(\mathcal{D}^{\leq0},\mathcal{D}^{\geq 0})$ (this however does not imply that $i^*=i^!$). Or at least, this is what I believe we have shown with Fosco Loregian in http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.03913 Assuming our result is correct (which may well not be the case), the natural questions are:

- is this actually true also for triangulated categories? (I have not been able to locate a statement like this in the literature)
- it is this maybe false for a general triangulated category but true for a triangulated category which is the homotopy category of a stable $\infty$-category?
- is this always manifestly false for triangulated categories? (something that would make me suspect of some mistake in my argument for stable $\infty$-categories, or a hint of the fact that giving a recollement situation in the stable setting is such a strong requirement that there are actually no natural examples of stable recollements)

Comment: Have you glanced at Appendix A in Higher Algebra? Lurie has a bunch of theorems on recollement of infty-cats and stable infty-cats etc. In any case, I would be very surprised if the stable infty-category story for t-structures is any different from the case of triangulated categories- after all, t-structures are defined on the homotopy category.

Comment: Also I'm confused by the statement that the stable infty category case is nicer because 'push outs and pullbacks are the same'. The analog of this statement is that the triangles in a triangulated category behave simultaneously like cofiber and fiber sequences. But maybe I should go look at your proof and see what's used...

Comment: Where exactly in appendix A? I can remember having performed a text search on Higher Algebra for recollements but that failed, so I missed the treatment in Appendix A. But now I've gone through it and I see it is actually relevant, thanks! Could you pint me to a precise point in the appendix that would be great. Me too would be surprised of a different behaviour in the triangulated case, the only explanations I can figure are a mistake in our proof or the fact that homotopy categories of stable categories are a bit special among triangulated categories.

Comment: Concerning triangles in a triangulated category behaving simultaneusly as fiber and cofiber sequences, I'ma a bit confused: see Theorem 7.1.11 in Hovey's book. The point seems to be that in a general triangulated category $\Sigma$ and $\Omega$ are adjoint but not inverse each other. But I may be missing some point here.

Comment: @domenicofiorenza $\Sigma$ is an equivalence by the definition of triangulated category...

Comment: Surely they are equivalences, but it is not clear to me they are inverse each other. In Theorem 7.1.11 in Hovey the composition $\Sigma\Omega$ appears, and were it the identity one would indeed have that cofiber sequences and fiber sequences coincide. But again I may be misunderstunding what Hovey writes there.

Comment: @domenicofiorenza They must be inverse to each other because they form an adjunction.  This is a general category-theoretic fact, of course.

Comment: @domenicofiorenza: perhaps you're confusing the model category with the underlying homotopy category? And the relevant section in the appendix is the one with "recollement" in the title, section A.8. Make sure you're looking at the most recent edition of HA from his website.

Comment: Most relevant to this question would be: A.8.1 for the definition of recollement, A.8.2 warning that recollement is *not* symmetric in the pieces (one should act like sheaves on a closed thing and the other as sheaves on the open complement), and A.8.16 and A.8.19 where he characterizes recollements of stable infty cats. None of this mentions t-structures but, again, I think that the t-structure story should be exactly the same as in BBD because it only involves the homotopy categories

Comment: @Adeel Khan: of course you are right, this shows how much that Theorem 7.1.11 in Hovey's book has been confusing me in this issue of fiber vs. cofiber sequences in triangulated categories :(

Comment: @DylanWilson: your remark about A.8.2 is right, but we *never* say that a recollement is symmetric in the pieces (this is false, in triangulated as well as in stable setting). What we say, instead, is (Scholium 4.4 in the paper) "a pleasant consequence of Rorschach lemma is that, since according to [BBD82, pag. 45] the diagram of 2-categories obtained reversing 2-cells in Def. 3.1 (namely, the diagram where the rôles of $i_L , i_R$ and $q_L , q_R$ are interchanged) is again a recollement, [...]

Comment: [...]  the glued t-structure along the initial recollement $r$ is the same as the t-structure glued along the dual recollement $r^{op}$."

It is not the same recollement, but generates the same gluings. Is this result known to be true/false in classical setting? BBD does not mention at all this issue.

Comment: @DylanWilson: your comment on "don't be scared of triangles and think of them as if they really were fiber/cofiber sequences" has been enlighting. Now I see how, with the due care, the triangulated formalism is much closer to the stable $\infty$-one than I was seeing before. In particular I am now confident Fosco and me can go step by step in our proof and reproduce it in the triangulated setting. Will keep you informed. Many thanks to Adeel Khan, too: those "take a pause and go back to basics!" suggestions have been essential to this "how I learned to stop worrying and love the triangles"

Comment: I echo Domenico's thanks and I kindly ask you an opinion about whether what we proved in our 4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 5.5 and 5.8 constitutes a new result.

Comment: Re-checking our proof to make it nearer to *Faisceaux Pervers*, I noticed a mysterious statement right after the end of the proof of the fact that there exists a recollée t-structure: "Nous n'aurons pas à utiliser, dans la suite de ces notes, la réciproque suivante à 1.4.10". What is the "reciprocal" of 1.4.10 again?

Answer (score 4):

The unexpected (and actually undue) symmetric behavior of stable recollements noticed in http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.03913 (Lemma 4.3 of version 1, therein called the Rorschach lemma) turned out to be the far reaching consequence of a typo in one of the commutative diagrams on page 9. This has now been corrected (i.e., Lemma 4.3, together with all its corollaries, has been removed).
Luckily, this was only minimally affecting the remaining part of the article, which has now been revised accordingly.